# Splitting written class into two files (C++)

Tags: c++, class

So, I have a  C++ class written in the `main.cpp` file of the project,like this:

```
class CAPiece
{
public:
    CAPiece(char cColor) : mcColor(cColor) {}
    ~CAPiece() {}
    virtual char GetPiece() = 0;
    char GetColor() {
        return mcColor;
    }
    bool IsLegalMove(int iSrcRow, int iSrcCol, int iDestRow, int iDestCol, CAPiece* qpaaBoard[8][8]) {
        CAPiece* qpDest = qpaaBoard[iDestRow][iDestCol];
        if ((qpDest == 0) || (mcColor != qpDest->GetColor())) {
            return AreSquaresLegal(iSrcRow, iSrcCol, iDestRow, iDestCol, qpaaBoard);
        }
        return false;
    }
private:
    virtual bool AreSquaresLegal(int iSrcRow, int iSrcCol, int iDestRow, int iDestCol, CAPiece* qpaaBoard[8][8]) = 0;
    char mcColor;
};
```

Is there a way to transfer it to the two separate files created by the Visual Studio Class Manager, without completely recoding it? (By two separate I mean `CAPiece.h` and `CAPiece.cpp` files)

Comment: Begin by putting the class definition in a *header file* that you can `#include`.

Comment: "*without completely recoding*": You just need to cut-and-paste the class definition from this file into the header file. The function implementations don't *need* to be outside the class in a `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

Is as simple as creating the two files, cutting copying things inside and then adding `#include "CAPiece.h"` at the beginning of files in which you need this class.

`CAPiece.h`:

```cpp
class CAPiece
{
public:
    CAPiece(char cColor);
    ~CAPiece();
    virtual char GetPiece() = 0;
    char GetColor();
    bool IsLegalMove(int iSrcRow, int iSrcCol, int iDestRow, int iDestCol, CAPiece* qpaaBoard[8][8]); 

private:
    virtual bool AreSquaresLegal(int iSrcRow, int iSrcCol, int iDestRow, int iDestCol, CAPiece* qpaaBoard[8][8]) = 0;
    char mcColor;
};
```

`CAPiece.cpp`

```cpp
#include "CaPiece.h"

CAPiece::CAPiece(char cColor) 
       : mcColor(cColor) 
{}
CAPiece::~CAPiece() 
{}
char CAPiece::GetColor() 
{
   return mcColor;
}
bool CAPiece::CAPieceIsLegalMove(int iSrcRow, int iSrcCol, int iDestRow, int iDestCol, CAPiece* qpaaBoard[8][8]) 
{
    CAPiece* qpDest = qpaaBoard[iDestRow][iDestCol];
    if ((qpDest == 0) || (mcColor != qpDest->GetColor())) {
       return AreSquaresLegal(iSrcRow, iSrcCol, iDestRow, iDestCol, qpaaBoard);
    }
    return false;
}
```